# How to properly invoke a custom component editor form for a component in delphi

Tags: delphi, components, custom-controls

I'm getting access violation when calling the Edit method of TComponentEditor class:

```
    type
      TLBIWXDataGridEditor = class(TComponentEditor)
      public
        function GetVerbCount: Integer; override;
        function GetVerb(Index: Integer): string; override;
        procedure ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); override;
        procedure Edit; override;
      end;
```

Here is the overridden Edit Method:

```
    procedure TLBIWXDataGridEditor.Edit;
    var
      _DsgForm: TLBIWXDataGridDesigner;
    begin
      _DsgForm := TLBIWXDataGridDesigner(Application);
      try
        _DsgForm.DataGrid := TLBIWXDataGrid(Self.Component);
        _DsgForm.ShowModal;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(_DsgForm);
      end;
    end;
```

All TLBIWXDataGrid properties will be changeable only inside the design form, because it doesn't have any published properties.

When calling the Edit method by double clicking the component at design time I either get AV or the IDE Crashes abruptly.

I don't think the problem is related to the other overridden methods, but here are their implementations:

```
    procedure TLBIWXDataGridEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
    begin
      case Index of
        0: MessageDlg ('add info here', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
        1: Self.Edit;
      end;
    end;

    function TLBIWXDataGridEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): string;
    begin
      case Index of
        0: Result := '&About...';
        1: Result := '&Edit...';
      end;
    end;

    function TLBIWXDataGridEditor.GetVerbCount: Integer;
    begin
      result := 2;
    end;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd have to brush up on component editors to tackle this. On a side note, that's quite an odd class name. I'd try to make it more simplified, even if it means spelling out one more word. 5 characters capital prefix is kinda intense for people to remember when writing code.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. There aren’t any methods implemented yet. The design form is empty. It only has the TLBIWXDataGrid property that points to a field. By saying that you need to take a closer look, I Imagine that the editor as depicted in the thread is fine. Am I right?

Comment: By the way, IWX stands for IntraWebExtra. LB are just my name initials.

Comment: Try setting a break point and let the debugger show you where the violation is occurring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```pascal
_DsgForm := TLBIWXDataGridDesigner(Application);
```

It is *typecasting* the `Application` object into a `TLBIWXDataGridDesigner`, which will not work.

Use this instead:

```pascal
_DsgForm := TLBIWXDataGridDesigner.Create(Application);
```

Or this, since you are freeing the dialog manually, so it does not need an `Owner` assigned:

```pascal
_DsgForm := TLBIWXDataGridDesigner.Create(nil);
```

Comment: Thanx Remy, what a lack of attention.